# Easiest way to display data in PyQt from my Sqlite database in a table?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, user-interface, pyqt4

```
def showdata(self):
    sender=self.sender()
    self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text()+' was pressed.')
    with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as db:
        cursor=db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('select* from Item Order BY Name ASC')
        product=cursor.fetchall()
        product=str(product)
        print(len(product))
        self.l.setText(str(product)) #this prints the database headers to a label inside my gui
        self.l124.setText(show) #this prints the database rows to a label inside my gui
```

This calls to my sqlite database and print all the data out in brackets in one line, such as (2, 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test')], with 2 being the unique id, and the other values input by the user. It also print out the database headers, separately to the rows, I would like to have them together to add simplicity. If any more information is required to aid me with my problem, or any code, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think in terms of processing the results one row at a time instead of *en masse*.

```
cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.execute('select* from Item Order BY Name ASC')
self.setupHeaderLabels(cursor.description)
for row in cursor:
    self.showOneRow(row)
```

Then just implement the `setupHeaderLabels` and `showOneRow` methods.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I worked from what you said and got the headers working how I wanted.However, I still cannot get the rows to show up in the gui, which may be to do with connecting to the label within the for loop.

Comment: @Jurisdiction Baby steps! Look up how to _add a row_ to the table (it won't take you long to search!) given some data in a particular row. Try doing it with a single column of the table; it's the simplest case. Then try doing it with multiple columns, getting the data from the row. You can save the row names from the code to set up the header labels if you want; it's a good use of a field.